# docker-compose can not use private IP

Tags: docker, consul

I am trying to run 2 containers in docker-compose. My docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '2'
services:

  consul:
    image: "consul:0.8.3"
    hostname: "consul"
    command: "agent -server -client=0.0.0.0 -retry-join=10.30.1.97 -retry-join=10.30.1.42 -bootstrap-expect=3 -ui"
    ports:
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8300:8300"
      - "8600:53/udp"
  vault:
    depends_on:
      - consul
    image: "vault"
    hostname: "vault"
    links:
      - "consul:consul"
    environment:
      VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    volumes:
      - ./tools/wait-for-it.sh:/wait-for-it.sh
      - ./config/vault:/config
      - ./config/vault/policies:/policies
    entrypoint: /wait-for-it.sh -t 20 -h consul -p 8500 -s -- vault server -config=/config/with-consul.hcl
```

The problem I get right at the begining is that consul container is not using IP 10.30.1.134 (The IP of the host machine)
Instead it is using I think a bridge network:

```
2017/07/10 10:09:12 [INFO] raft: Node at 172.18.0.2:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state (Leader: "")
```

How can I force it to use 10.30.1.134?

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:f5:74:4c:ad:9e
          inet addr:10.30.1.134  Bcast:10.30.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4f5:74ff:fe4c:ad9e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:9907809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17142864 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1328463684 (1.3 GB)  TX bytes:2178517759 (2.1 GB)

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose by default creates own network inside a docker environment. So, answering your question - to use host network you should use:

```
network_mode: "host"
```

as described here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

But this is rarely something that you actually need. Port mapping that you define already creates port forwarding between host and containers. E.g. host_machine_ip:8200 would be forwarded to your vault container. And this way you can decide which ports specifically are being exposed.

Comment: My problem is not the communication between consul and vault container. I am starting simular docker-compose.yml on second and 3th servers and they can not talk to each other because conusul doesn't use 10.30.1.0 network

Comment: Your port binding exposes these ports on 0.0.0.0 so they should be perfectly accessible. Check your firewall. You can also expose ports on specific interface (and not on all interface like it does by default). E.g.

    `ports:
      - "10.30.1.134:8400:8400"`

Comment: Tried it - not working:  `consul_1  |        Client Addr: 0.0.0.0 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
consul_1  |       Cluster Addr: 172.18.0.2 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302) `    The Cluster address is at the bridge network and is not accessible from other nodes

Comment: `* Failed to join 10.30.1.97: dial tcp 10.30.1.97:8301: getsockopt: connection refused`

Comment: This is not specifically a docker related issue. As docker does what it supposed to here. Anyway, you are connecting to 8301 and you did not expose that port. Add `"8301:8301"` to `ports`. You could also bind cluster to a different ip by `-bind` argument. But it seems that `8302` is already used for WAN communication, so you can also try exposing and using that.

Comment: OK I think network_mode: "host" and adding -bind fixed the issue.  It took me some time for I was playing with settings. Thank you very much.